# Get all child node using Parent ID

Tags: mysql

Hi I have table named tbl_user where i want to retrieve all the child node of parent node.

Every parent id has left and right node and respectively.

**My Table structure and Data**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Sep 19, 2017 at 08:29 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mlm`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_position` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sponser_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plan_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_created` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_user`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (`id`, `user_id`, `full_name`, `display_name`, `email`, `mobile`, `password`, `address`, `country_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `parent_id`, `user_position`, `sponser_id`, `plan_id`, `status`, `user_created`) VALUES
(18, 'OR201701', 'Chita Ranjan Mirdha', 'Chitta', 'chitta@gmail.com', '9861180448', '317419d46c44c40b99f7351739dbec74', NULL, 99, 24, 719, NULL, 'center', NULL, 1, 'active', '2017-09-17'),
(19, 'OR317639', 'Binayak Das', 'Binayak', 'talk2binayak@gmail.com', '9861180448', '317419d46c44c40b99f7351739dbec74', NULL, 99, 11, 222, 'OR201701', 'left', 'OR201701', 1, 'Pending', '2017-09-17'),
(20, 'OR480484', 'Soumya Ranjan Das', 'Soumya', 'soumya002000@gmail.com', '9439149608', '317419d46c44c40b99f7351739dbec74', NULL, 99, 24, 722, 'OR201701', 'right', 'OR201701', 1, 'active', '2017-09-20'),
(23, 'OR594192', 'Sidharth Das', 'Sidharth', 'sidharth@gmail.com', '9861180448', '317419d46c44c40b99f7351739dbec74', NULL, 99, 3, 85, 'OR480484', 'left', 'OR201701', 2, 'Pending', '2017-09-17'),
(24, 'OR355157', 'Rohit Kerketta', 'Rohit', 'rohit@gmail.com', '9861180448', '74b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5', NULL, 99, 20, 693, 'OR480484', 'right', 'OR201701', 1, 'Pending', '2017-09-17'),
(25, 'OR435604', 'Jabesh Ghanta', 'Jabesh', 'jabesh@gmail.com', '9861180448', '74b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5', NULL, 99, 24, 719, 'OR317639', 'left', 'OR201701', 2, 'Pending', '2017-09-17'),
(26, 'OR539892', 'Abhishek Behera', 'Daddu', 'abhishek@gmail.com', '9861180448', '11ddbaf3386aea1f2974eee984542152', NULL, 99, 12, 281, 'OR317639', 'right', 'OR201701', 1, 'Pending', '2017-09-18'),
(27, 'OR776071', 'Lalatendu Das', 'LULU', 'talk2lalatendu@gmail.com', '9861180488', '8f60c8102d29fcd525162d02eed4566b', NULL, 99, 11, 209, 'OR355157', 'left', 'OR355157', 1, 'Pending', '2017-09-18'),
(28, 'OR119885', 'Jyotirmaya Das', 'Tikana', 'jmd@gmail.com', '9861180448', '8f60c8102d29fcd525162d02eed4566b', NULL, 99, 5, 112, 'OR355157', 'right', 'OR355157', 1, 'Pending', '2017-09-20'),
(29, 'OR135842', 'Ashish Kumar Samantray', 'Asish', 'asish.samantray@gmail.com', '9861180448', 'decc8686654b465e5313259325149a86', NULL, 99, 24, 716, 'OR435604', 'left', 'OR355157', 2, 'Pending', '2017-09-19');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I have tried a lot to get all child node which user is logged in means logged in user is the parent node.

I have user_id have the parent_id. Once you will import the data into mysql you will have an idea about data and structure.

For better understand I am uploading the tree structure.[image]

This is the binary structure of my data. But i want the data also in a table
like below

[image]

As per my current query what i have given above is showing 6 results. But the query should show the 9 results as per binary tree.

I think explained well. if any doubt please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. I think, this will work for you.

SELECT *
FROM tbl_user
WHERE parent_id = 'OR201701'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_user
WHERE parent_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE parent_id = 'OR201701')